# Angular2 cast string to JSON

Tags: json, angular

What is the right syntax to cast a string to JSON in Angular2?
I tried:

```
var someString;
someString.toJSON(); //or someString.toJson();
```

it says: `someString.toJSON is not a function`

I'm lost because it was working with Angular1.

---

If I try to add an attribute directly on my string (which is formatted like a true JSON):

```
var someString;
someString.att = 'test';
```

it says: `TypeError: Cannot create property 'att' on string '...'`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Angular2 uses JavaScript functions unlike Angular1.

Angular1 implements its own functions which is a bad thing.

In Angular2 just use pure JavaScript.

```
var json = JSON.parse(string);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `JSON.parse()`

```
var someString: string = "your JSON String here";
var jsonObject : any = JSON.parse(someString)
```